# How to understand the next values of a comparator inverting with hysteresis (Schmitt Trigger)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, homework, hysteresis

I have my test graded and I'm curious about a question, since I think it's badly graded and I may need to request a revision.

I have been told there is a comparator inverter with hysteresis so \$|V_{SAT}|=2V_{CTR}\$, (or \$2V_{st}\$, it depends on the bibliography)  \$R_i=100\Omega\$ and the next graph (edited from a book but it's the same given).

[image]

I have no \$V_{ref}\$ and the question is to calculate the value of the feedback resistor.

I did the next process

\$V_{LT}=-V_{th}=8V\$

\$V_{HT}=V_{th}=12V\$

\$V_{H}=+V_{sat}=2V_{CTR}\$

\$V_{L}=-V_{sat}=-2V_{CTR}\$

\$
+V_{th}=V_{Ht}=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{F}}(+V_{sat})
\$

\$
-V_{th}=V_{Lt}=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{F}}(-V_{sat})
\$

\$
V_{CTR}=\frac{V_{Ht}+V_{Lt}}{2}=\frac{8+12}{2}=10V
\$
\$
V_{sat}=2(10V)=20V
\$

\$
V_{Ht}=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{F}}(+V_{sat})
\$

\$
12\,V=\frac{100\Omega}{100\Omega+R_{F}}(20\,V)
\$

\$
R_{F}=\frac{100\Omega}{12\,V}(20\,V)-100\Omega=66.66\Omega
\$

\$
V_{Lt}=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{F}}(-V_{sat})
\$

\$
V_{Lt}=\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{F}}(-V_{sat})
\$

\$
8\,V=\frac{100\,\Omega}{100\Omega+R_{F}}(20\,V)
\$
\$
R_{F}=\frac{1200V\Omega}{8V}=150\Omega
\$

Finally I answered the \$R_{F}=150\Omega\$ at least, and it was marked as wrong.
What's the right answer?

Comment: Draw your circuit please and mark on it all the nodes you mention or, if you want to sove this yourself; use a simulator.

Comment: As you present a graph marked with Vs and Vo, and none of the voltages in your text are marked on it, you're making the question very difficult to follow. Factor in that Vth = 8V but -Vth = 12V /= -8V and you are probably confusing yourself long before you get to an answer.

Comment: ROFL *badly graded and I may need to request a revision.*   That always goes over well.

Comment: @Andyaka,there was no circuit provided, and it will take me a bit of time to make the simulation, but I intend to do so.

Comment: A circuit is usually helpful no matter the simplicity of the perceived circuit and the pain in the arse drawing it takes. I always draw a circuit and usually (nay very very usually) thar first circuit goes into a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot describes your design spec. and perhaps you made false assumptions. Let's review why you were marked low.  For me it is a case of unclear specs in your question/answer without a schematic and clear assumptions, **yet the plot is clear**.

So let's make a list of test specs, from which you can make a design that works.

**Spec:**

1. Vo goes high from -8 to 8V  for Vs(source) from low >8V
2. Vo goes low from +8 to -8V for Vs exceeding  12V input and only then when returning to 8V input does the output switch.
3. This tells me the arrows are in the wrong direction or that another stage of inversion is needed, so that should be confirmed but let's assume the opposite correct direction using the non-inverting input with positive feedback. ***(rather than the inverting input with the output inverted on a 2nd stage)***
4. This means the input threshold mean, **Vth** is 10V and hysteresis is +/-4 or **8Vpp** for an output swing of +/-8V or **16Vpp**.
5. **Vth** mean is greater than the Vo max  so there must be some level shifting on the comparator, but **it is clear from the Vpp ratios (Vo/Vs)[pp] that the hysteresis is 50% of the output.**

- now if you agree to either of my assumptions, you can easily design the comparator.

**Moral of the story is** bad answers come from bad specs
and I may have made false assumptions.  But if you state the assumptions clearly, then analyze the assumptions correctly to solve, then you might get more marks, even if you misunderstood.;

This is a common issue with clients converting a "paper napkin" idea into a "design spec" then reviewing the assumptions and if OK , then proceeding with the design.

Does anyone want to offer a schematic solution?  (challenge)

Comment: Thanks, Its clear this way, and indeed this graph is good enough to develop the assumptions done.Either way, I requested the revision under the same argument you writed, the arrows are wrongways.

Comment: The problem comes in realizing how to do it with the Non inverting input used for both feedback and input signal with attenuation, gain and offset and Ri=100 ohms  and  I  assume Vi=Vs for  Vlt, Vht = 8,12V is harder than it sounds and given less thought by other experts

Comment: In the end for a non-inverting Schmitt trigger , I would use a spreadsheet to solve the equations or write out or use a simulator to choose scaled new offset and hysteresis  or keep gain and offset independent and use an analog inverter